# Error while Doctrine Migration with Symfony upgrade 2.8-> 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony3.x

i have upgraded symfony version 2.8->3.4 and i have issues with

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

the error im getting is :

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

i didn't change any parameters of database host and port from 2.8 and was working on 2.8 so hopefully this issue is regarding the symfony upgrade.

parameters.yml as follows

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    symfony_environment: dev
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 8801
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    database_cert: null
    database_opts: null
    database_version: null
```

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your mysql service is running...

Also, have a look to your configuration files (parameters.yml)

Comment: thansk for the reply i checked the parameters.yml and i can access mysql in my localhost
im updating the parameters.yml here as well

Comment: Great, glad you can fix it

Comment: Hi Val, Sorry still my issue is not fixed. getting the same error. and i even tried the old version which is 2.8 and tried doctorine:migrate even though its not working